# No matching editors or conversion strategy found , composite key including MayToOne mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having following error, it seems everything is correct, but I think I am missing something importand

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.Long' to required type 'com.mfs.ir.domain.IrMatchrules' for property 'matchrule': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.convertIfNecessary(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:590)



@ActiveProfiles("it")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@SpringBootTest
public class IrMrIterationMappingIT {

    @Autowired private IterationMappingRepository iterationMappingRepository;

    @Autowired private MatchrulesRepository matchrulesRepository;


    @Test
    @Transactional
    public void shouldHaveRecordSavedCorrectly() {


        IrMatchrules inputIrMatchrules =  matchrulesRepository.save(
                IrMatchrules.builder()
                .matchruleId(1l)
                        .portfolioCode("PCODE")
                        .build());

        IrMrIterationMapping inputIrMrIterationMapping = IrMrIterationMapping.builder().
                iterationType(MatchRuleIterationType.MANY_MANY).
                matchrule(inputIrMatchrules).build();

        iterationMappingRepository.save(inputIrMrIterationMapping);

        IrMrIterationMapping result =  iterationMappingRepository.findById(IrMrIterationMappingPK.builder().iterationType(MatchRuleIterationType.MANY_MANY).matchrule(inputIrMatchrules).build()).orElseThrow();

        assertThat(result.getIterationType()).isEqualTo(inputIrMrIterationMapping.getIterationType());
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        iterationMappingRepository.deleteAllInBatch();
        matchrulesRepository.deleteAllInBatch();
    }

public class IrMrIterationMappingPK implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MATCHRULE_ID")
    private IrMatchrules matchrule;

    @Id
    @Convert(converter = MatchRuleIterationTypeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "ITERATION_ID")
    private MatchRuleIterationType iterationType;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "IR_MATCHRULES", schema = "RECON_OWNER", catalog = "")
public class IrMatchrules {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MATCHRULE_ID")
    private long matchruleId;
    @Column(name="MATCHRULE_NAME")
    private String matchruleName;

    @Column(name="ITERATION_TYPE")
    private Long iterationType;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with EmbeddedId

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Embeddable
public class IrMrIterationMappingPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MATCHRULE_ID")
    private IrMatchrules matchrule;

    @Convert(converter = MatchRuleIterationTypeConverter.class)
    @Column(name = "ITERATION_ID")
    private MatchRuleIterationType iterationType;
}


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "IR_MR_ITERATION_MAPPING", schema = "RECON_OWNER", catalog = "")
//@IdClass(com.mfs.ir.domain.IrMrIterationMappingPK.class)
public class IrMrIterationMapping implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    IrMrIterationMappingPK IrMrIterationMappingPK;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are annotating matchRule with @Id. This will make it store a long Value. Remove it. If the problem persists
make the following changes :
In class IrMrIterationMappingPK

```
public class IrMrIterationMappingPK implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private IrMatchrules matchrule;
    //rest of your code
}
```

In class IrMatchrules

```
public class IrMatchrules {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MATCHRULE_ID")
    private long matchruleId;
    @Column(name="MATCHRULE_NAME")
    private String matchruleName;

    @Column(name="ITERATION_TYPE")
    private Long iterationType;
   
    //Add the below line-
     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<IrMrIterationMappingPK> irMrIterationMappingPKs;

}
```